# Store Json response in Database android

Tags: android, json, database, offline

```
@Override
public void onResponse(VolleyResponseBean response) {
    if (response.isValidateWebServiceType(response)) {
        switch (response.getWebServiceType()) {
            case GET_LATEST_POST:
                    ArrayList<LatestPost> resposneObject = (ArrayList<LatestPost>) (ArrayList<?>)response.getWordPressDataList();
                    LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Response sucessful" + resposneObject );
                latestPostTitle = new String[resposneObject.size()];
                latestPostImage = new String[resposneObject.size()];
                latestPostId = new Double[resposneObject.size()];
                latestPostDate = new String[resposneObject.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<resposneObject.size();++i){
                    mapLatestPost = (Map<String,Object>)resposneObject.get(i);
                    mapLatestTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapLatestPost.get("title");
                    latestPostTitle[i] = (String) mapLatestTitle.get("rendered");
                    mapLatestContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapLatestPost.get("content");
                    latestPostImage[i] = (String) mapLatestContent.get("medium");
                    latestPostId[i] = (Double) mapLatestPost.get("id");
                    latestPostDate[i] = (String) mapLatestPost.get("date");
                }
```

Here after getting response i am storing all in string variables, arrays of string etc. but i want to store the overall response in database for offline mode. m stuck now. please help how can i implement database now.

Comment: Study Content Provider and Sqlite Database

Comment: Thanks @Anurag.but facing problem to store JSON response which contains URL of image also. want to store response in object relationship management(ORM) but unable to resolve this issue. Trying n surfing more to get solution but unable to do.